# Taking Input in sub-linear time from a file

Tags: c++

I have a list of nodes(string,value). Can i scan it in sublinear time. Further i need to process it so that each search query on string can be done in sublinear time. 
Also can anyone be more specific if sublinear means less than O(n) or can it be O(n)? I am using CPP

Comment: What do YOU mean with sublinear? And how do you manage to scan a list in sublinear time? O(n) is linear, so I would guess that sublinear means anything faster than that, e.g. constant but then I wonder how you can scan the list in constant time...

Comment: Well, O(log(n)) you might call "sublinear" as well...

Comment: @tobi303 ...but reading `n` items requires `n` operations, doesn't it?

Comment: @CiaPan yes, thats why I do not understand what he means with "scan it in sublinear time"

Comment: "Sublinear" means "strictly better than linear (i.e. O(n))". ("sub" means "under" or "below".) You can't scan a list without looking at each item, which makes it linear in the size of the list. Structures which support lookups in sublinear time are well known (binary trees, hash tables, etc).

Comment: I second CiaPan; to my understanding, it is impossible to read a complete input in sublinear time. Please be more specific about the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

*Scan* usually means 'read every item (in some, often predefined, order)`. If you *read every item* you perform at least linear number of *read the next item* operations. We assume the operation takes some time, usually constant, sometimes equal or greater than some minimum time, so executing a scan requires some time at least proportional to the number of items processed (the list length).

So the answer is **NO**, you can't do that in sublinear time–unless your machine can replicate itself *on the fly* and split data into parts to be handled by each of descendant machines. Even then the splitting must be done in constant time despite the data size, or the splitting overhead can easily eat up all savings.